# YARN FairScheduler configuration

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop3

[Resource model in Hadoop 3](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceModel.html) allows us to define custom resource types. I did some googling but couldn't find anything that would tell how can the YARN FairScheduler be configured to distribute/isolate these resources among its pools.

Answer (score 0):

Found JIRA [[Umbrella] YARN Resource Profiles phase#2 enhancements](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-7069), with some sub-tasks related to RM UI- and inner workings of the FairScheduler, e.g. "[Add support for dynamic resource updates with multiple resource types](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-6612)". As of July 2019, some of the sub-tasks are still open.